# remove duplicated array item

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

```
var arr = ["Chandelier", "Big Girls Cry", "Burn the Pages", "Eye of the Needle", "Hostage", "Straight for the Knife", "Fair Game", "Elastic Heart", "Free the Animal", "Fire Meet Gasoline", "Cellophane", "Dressed In Black", "Chandelier", "Elastic Heart", "Chandelier", "Chandelier", "Elastic Heart", "Elastic Heart", "Big Girls Cry", "Big Girls Cry"];

 $.each(arr, function(i,obj){
console.log(obj);
});
```

How can I make sure my array is unique?

Comment: Wow, search before posting

Comment: @WesFoster I'm using $.each in this case.

Comment: So are you asking for a method to remove duplicates using `$.each`?

Comment: @WesFoster obviously.

Comment: Not obvious, actually.

Comment: It would be more obvious if you question stated something like "I have a constraint where I must do this in a `$.each` loop"

Comment: @NicholeA.Miler your question is asking how to dedupe the array _before_ you loop over it with `each`.

Answer (score 1):

With [`Array#filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and a temporary object.

```js
var arr = ["Chandelier", "Big Girls Cry", "Burn the Pages", "Eye of the Needle", "Hostage", "Straight for the Knife", "Fair Game", "Elastic Heart", "Free the Animal", "Fire Meet Gasoline", "Cellophane", "Dressed In Black", "Chandelier", "Elastic Heart", "Chandelier", "Chandelier", "Elastic Heart", "Elastic Heart", "Big Girls Cry", "Big Girls Cry"],
    unique = arr.filter(function (a) {
        if (!this[a]) {
            this[a] = true;
            return true;
        }
    }, {});    
    
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(unique, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: I'm using $.each to get each name and push it somewhere, how does this help in my case?

Comment: why do you need $.each?

Comment: @NinaScholz -- Probably the OP. +1 from me because your answer did indeed answer the question that was asked...not the question that wasn't asked. :)